# Putting permission and authorization logic in the database

Tags: security, database-design, web-applications, architecture

I have a conceptual/architectural question I'd like to get some input on. Before I go into the details, I'd like to mention that I am well-aware of the arguments against putting application logic into the database, and the importance of maintaining abstraction and separation of concerns.

That being said, the application in question is a fairly simple one, in which performance is relatively more important than best practices. It is a new app, built with very modern technologies but on old school principles (stored procs, no ORM, etc).

I have a fairly complex "summary view" which is going to be driven by data provided by a stored procedure. Most of the elements of this view are going to have permission logic (not trivial, but nothing too complex) which will change both the appearance as well as the nature of the data based on the permissions of the currently logged in user (i.e. some data could be anonymized, other could be hidden, etc).

All data, as well as membership and ACL records, are stored in the same database.

So, the question is where to put the logic of applying user rights. The two options are:

> 1) Bring back all relevant data from the database into domain objects, then apply permissions in the middle-tier
>
> 2) Pass a user ID to the stored proc, and have it pass back an already prepared result to the middle-tier

At first look, conceptually, the no-brainer seems to be to throw it into the middle-tier (1st option) and leave the database concerned with what it does best - reading and writing data. However, the stored procedure will already be "tailored" to the specific view (think something along the lines of a report), and not used for anything else; thus, it just seems easier and lighter to process the permissions inside of the stored proc and bring back a prepared result with all the permissions already applied (a result that would have less data), rather than bringing back ALL the data into the middle tier and processing permissions there (eventually to discard half of the data anyway).

I am a bit torn and would appreciate some input. Intuitively, the 2nd option seems like a better fit, but "feels" very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Design the stored procedure to accept privileges enabled or features to use, e.g.

```
PROCEDURE retrieve_data (id_or_other_params,
                         anonymize := FALSE,
                         hide := FALSE,
                         some_other_feature := FALSE);
```

Procedure concerns now data retrieval only, with modifying options read from external source. Now let middle tier authenticate the user, decide which options to use and pass them to the procedure.

Comment: That's a cool idea, but it wouldn't really work for my case. The permissions are per-row and are based on an ACL which is also stored for the database; for example, row 2 refers to entity #2 and the permissions will depend on the requesting user's ACL for entity #2, and so on. I ended up doing it in the database just because its faster (will possibly refactor later). Thanks for the input, though!